# Bootstrap 3.0.0 fixed menu bar, not working correctly on android phones

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap-3

I got a problem with Bootstrap's fixed menu bar.

Works fine on Desktop browsers, but on phones (especially on Android phones) the menu bar behaves weird.

The logo is not always present on a page load, and when you wipe over the position where it is supposed to be, it suddenly shows up. Also when changing the orientation to landscape, the toggle/collapse button is lost somewhere in the middle of the nav bar, and doesnt stay on the right side anymore.

It seems like fixed bars on Android are buggy...and the rendering is messed up somehow...

Has anybody seen the same weird behaviour before? Is there a good fix?

**Found a dirty workaround**, that somehow forces the android browser to rerender the elements mentioned above:

```
$("#navbar .logo img").width(31).width(32);
$("#navbar .logo img").height(31).width(32);

$("#navbar").hide();
$("#navbar").get(0).offsetHeight;
$("#navbar").show();
```

Obviously this code is rather silly ;) but it works...since it comes down to small css adjustments which are reversed right away, there might be a smarter solution to force a rerendering. However having the browser measure the offset of at least one of the involved elements seems to be crucial...